# Multiple annotation verticalLines using mapAs dataset

Tags: anychart

I would like to add vertical lines to graph as markers for interesting events.

The only way i can see to add multiple lines is to define multiple `controller.verticalLine` annotations like

```
controller.verticalLine({
xAnchor: "2007-09-23"
});

controller.verticalLine({
xAnchor: "2008-10-23"
});
```

Is it possible to do this nicer like

```
controller.verticalLine([{
 xAnchor: "2007-09-23"
},
{
 xAnchor: "2007-10-23"
},
{
 xAnchor: "2007-11-23"
 }]);
```

or better, pass it a data set using `mapAs`, where each value in the mapping would be a `xAnchor` value ?

```
var mapping = dataTable.mapAs({"value": 4});
controller.verticalLine(mapping);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the lines from the dataset with the custom field and get them from data with the get() method:
https://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.data.Mapping#get

```
mapping.get(i, "anchor"),
```

Like is shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/osub60ck/